# Dependabot version fails due to outdated flutter version

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dependabot

I am working on an open-source flutter project it uses Github's dependabot to manage its dependency versions.
But recently we upgraded our flutter to the latest version `Flutter: 3.7.3` and after that all of the Dependabot PRs are failing consistently.

Links of failing PRs:

1. https://github.com/PalisadoesFoundation/talawa/pull/1638
2. https://github.com/PalisadoesFoundation/talawa/pull/1639
3. https://github.com/PalisadoesFoundation/talawa/pull/1647
4. https://github.com/PalisadoesFoundation/talawa/pull/1648
5. https://github.com/PalisadoesFoundation/talawa/pull/1666

I found out that dependabot is deleting the `SHA256` property from all the pacakages. I think it's because dependabot is not having the latest flutter version.
This issues describes this situation better : https://github.com/PalisadoesFoundation/talawa/issues/1643

[image: deleted sha256 from pubspec.lock]

How can I upgrade the flutter version of dependabot to solve this?